# Spring Boot and Spring Data Moore Release

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I´m facing some strange version issues concerning Spring Boot with Spring Data (JDBC).
Excerpt from my pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Lovelace-SR10</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

When i use this combination above my tests run as expected.

Then, when i want to update to the current release train of the spring data team which is
 `<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Moore-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>` i even can´t run my tests anymore saying:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
```

Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**
If i comment the manual DataSourceConfiguration for Spring DATA JDBC my tests are running ...???
Somethings wrong with this and the new Moore Release?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

private final @NonNull Environment environment;

/**
 * NamedParameterJdbcOperations Bean.
 * Necessary for spring data jdbc module.
 *
 * @return NamedParameterJdbcOperations
 */
@Bean
NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations() {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}

/**
 * Naming strategy for naming entity columns
 *
 * @return PhysicalNamingStrategy
 * @see <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334685/how-to-tweak-namingstrategy-for-spring-data-jdbc/53335830#53335830">How to implement {@link NamingStrategy}</a>
 */
@Bean
public NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
    return new NamingStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
            Assert.notNull(property, "Property must not be null.");
            return ParsingUtils.reconcatenateCamelCase(property.getName(), "");
        }

        @Override
        public String getTableName(Class<?> type) {
            Assert.notNull(type, "Type must not be null.");
            return ParsingUtils.reconcatenateCamelCase(type.getSimpleName(), "");
        }
    };
}

/**
 * PlatformTransactionManager Bean.
 * Necessary for spring data jdbc module.
 *
 * @return PlatformTransactionManager
 */
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}

/**
 * DataSource Bean.
 * Necessary for spring data jdbc module.
 *
 * @return DataSource
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(this.environment.getRequiredProperty("de.thd.test.datasource.url"));
    hikariConfig.setUsername("test_user");
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    hikariConfig.setPassword("test");
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

Comment: I tried to solve this problem using debug in intellij and `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. Found that `org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE` does not have `IMPORT_BEAN_NAME_GENERATOR` and found that I should upgrade it to `org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.0.RELEASE`, but maven does not resolved it to that version, as old `org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.12` prevents. And there are some breaking changes in spring security (don't take me completely right), so be careful if you have security in your path. This can help you to narrow your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix for this issue:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1590

For the sake of completeness here the quote:
"*The reference that the stack trace complains about was introduced in Spring Framework 5.2, which you'd need to upgrade to use Moore with Spring Boot 2.1. 2.2 has already been updated to both Moore and Framework 5.2, i.e. it should work properly on its milestone and release candidate releases.*"*Oliver Drotbohm (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1590)